# Java AES PKCS7 - last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, aes, encryption, pkcs#7

I have an Python application that creates a few files encrypted with AES/PKCS7. I have to read those files with a Java service. But my code is throwing an exception:

"javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption"

Here's my decryption code:

```
public String Decrypt(String strText)
{
    try
    {
        // Text to decrypt
        byte[] test = strText.getBytes();

        //bytKey is the same key as Python app
        SecretKeySpec objKey = new SecretKeySpec(bytKey, "AES");
        Cipher objCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        objCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, objKey);

        // Here I got an exception >>
        byte[] bytValue = objCipher.doFinal(test);

        return new String(bytValue);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";

}
```

If I decode the encrypted text before step into `doFinal` I get another exception:

"javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted"

```
public String Decrypt(String strText)
{
    try
    {

        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] test = decoder.decodeBuffer(strText);

        SecretKeySpec objKey = new SecretKeySpec(bytKey, "AES");
        Cipher objCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        objCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, objKey);

        byte[] bytValue = objCipher.doFinal(test);

        return new String(bytValue);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";

}
```

I'm not an expert on encrypt/decrypt and I guess it's quite simple to solve.
Any ideas to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any ideas? I'm really stucked :/

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, please post a solution.